# Data loaded with measurement protocol doesn't reflect in some reports

Tags: google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We ran a website that is selling using partner websites. In order for us to see the sales data in Google Analytics and be able to create audience reflecting the buying users, we
record the Google Analytics user id and later on when we have the sales data we use Analytics Measurement Protocol to upload ecommerce data to Google Analytics and to shoot events that translates to Goal conversions. We also created audience in Google Adwords which is defined using the same Goal conversions. However, besides the ecommerce data itself which looks ok in Google Analytics, I'm unable to see the following:

1. Demographics data related to the conversions uploaded with Measurement Protocol. No numbers in this report related to sales.
2. Audience created is Google Adwords is very small, around 30, even though thousands of ecommerce and goal conversions data was uploaded.

Any idea?

Comment: Justo to make sure, the user id is something that would come from your backend. Do you really mean that, or do you record the client id (the id that is stored in the cookie) ?

Comment: 1 and 2 are things that are created within analytics.js  How exactly are you adding them to the measurement protocol yourself?    If you managed to figure out how to add the doubleclick cookie data I would be interested in seeing how.    Adwords is linked directly by google so I wouldn't even think that one was possible.

Comment: Yes, we record the google client id which is stored in the cookie and the same is used when using the measurement protocol. 
What I meant to say in #1 and #2 is that after I upload the sales data, the ecommerce data under product performance for example shows the data as expected. However, the ecommerce report, under demographic and age for example, doesn't show any data at all. Actually, only the data under the Conversion section and Acqusition->campagins shows data that makes sense. All other reports, including gender, age, geo, etc are showing no data when I'm selecting ecommerce.